# KVM - Sharing A Physical Hard Drive Between VMs

Tags: kvm-virtualization, storage

Installed Ubuntu 14.04 and will be ditching VirtualBox to go to KVM per some recommendations.

With that in mind, I have a full physical SATA disk that I would like to share between a few VMs.  Is this possible with KVM?

In essence, each of the VMs would mount this and use it to make backups on a daily basis of configuration and other files.

Comment: `VMs would mount this` - You really should export as NFS or something at just access it over the network.  Trying to juggle a physical connection between multiple VMs seems highly likely to fail in some weird way and lead to filesystem corruption.

Comment: I am currently using NFS with virtualbox - but it just seems to be pretty slow.  Was looking to see if there was something that required less configuration on the actual sever end and that would provide direct access with faster speeds.

Comment: VirtualBox is pretty slow and you shouldn't generalize your experience with it to other things. NFS is the way to go here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options the way I see it:

## Use NFS

as per other commenters - NFS seems to be the path of least resistance

## juggle disk assignment and use some orchestration tool

1. with KVM you can do things like "hot-plug" disk etc. via:

```
    $ virsh attach-disk ...
```

2. then inside VM that got this disk attached mount disk and do your backup
3. umount disk inside VM
4. on VM host detach disk:

```
    $ virsh detach-disk ...
```

5. rinse-and-repeat for the rest of VMs

to pull this off you'll need to run some orchestration - likely some Ansible/Puppet/Chef/whatever since your tasks span across several hosts.

Comment: NFS is a *filesystem*. The original question is about *disk*.

Comment: then option two: "juggle disk assignment"

Answer (score 1):

## General option 1

It's possible to share a physical drive, or in general, any block device between two KVM being run on the same host. Just pass device filename to `-drive` option.

## General option 2

If you need to share the drive between two VMs on two different hosts (in general), you need SAN (storage access network) in general.

It could be FibreChannel connection (the best performance) or iSCSI.

In both cases, you need initiator and target.

- Initiator - machine which 'consumes' block device.
- Target - machine  (or device)

Initiators - are also VM hosts. Connected block devices are passed as block devices to VMs by name.

### Tips

A must: `-drive format=raw, cache=off`
For the performance, `virtio` is highly recommended.